# how can i match exploded value with user session id?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) { 

     $imp_to=explode(',',$row['mail_to_user_id']);

     $imp_cc=explode(',',$row['mail_cc_user_id']);

if($imp_to == $_SESSION['user_id'] or $imp_cc == $_SESSION['user_id'] )
    {

    }
```

Comment: use in_array() function  may be get some help

Comment: use in_array($_SESSION['user_id'],$imp_to) or in_array($_SESSION['user_id'],$imp_cc)

Comment: Normalize your database.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This..

```
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) { 

     $imp_to=explode(',',$row['mail_to_user_id']);

     $imp_cc=explode(',',$row['mail_cc_user_id']);

    if(in_array($_SESSION['user_id'] ,$imp_to) || in_array($_SESSION['user_id'] ,$imp_cc))
    {

    }
```

Comment: try to make array of $imp_to and then drive the for loop and in for loop check if condition ..